# jQuery Hotkeys - unbinding?

Tags: jquery, dialog, hotkeys

I have a jQuery Dialog which initializes hotkeys as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).bind('keydown', '<%=(i+1)%>',function (evt) {
     // do stuff
  });
</script>
```

This loops through 1-9...

Problem is, if you close the dialog and then reopen the dialog. It keeps re-binding, so when you do a keydown on '1', it then runs twices, three times, four times, etc... it just keeps growing.

I tried killing the keybindings on dialog close with

```
$(document).unbind('keydown', '1');
$(document).unbind('keydown', '2');
$(document).unbind('keydown', '3');
$(document).unbind('keydown', '4');
$(document).unbind('keydown', '5'); 
$(document).unbind('keydown', '6');
$(document).unbind('keydown', '7');
$(document).unbind('keydown', '8');
$(document).unbind('keydown', '9');
```

But that had no effect. Any ideas on how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `.die()`   http://api.jquery.com/die/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) doesn't support the `eventData` argument, which is why your unbinds aren't working.

Off the top of my head, you have two different approaches here.  If these are the only document-level keydown bindings, you can to a "full" unbind as follows:

```
$(document).unbind('keydown'); // unbinds *all* keydown handers on the document
```

Alternatively, you can store your keydown handler as a non-anonymous function and keep a reference around to pass back to unbind when closing the dialog:

```
function onkeydown(evt) {
   // do stuff
}

$(document).bind('keydown', '<%=(i+1)%>', onkeydown);

// later, in the dialog's "shutdown" code:
$(document).unbind('keydown', onkeydown);
```

I'm not 100% positive how this works when the same function is bound multiple times, however.  You're probably better off eliminating the `eventData` and using `event.which` inside your event handler to determine which key was pressed (which would then only require the handler be bound once).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue using a namespace for the keydown event in conjunction with one()

note the .g in "keydown.g". That puts it in a separate scope which I can later unbind without unbinding every keydown in the document.

```
$(document).one("keydown.g", function(e) {
 // tab key
 if (e.which == "9") {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do something like focus on a field
  $("#target").focus();
  // once you've moved the focus, you can unbind and go back to tabbing normally
  $(document).unbind("keydown.g");
 } 
});
```

<3 Jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $(document).bind('keydown', '<%=(i+1)%>',function (evt) {
        // do stuff
    });
} );
</script>
```

This method binds events one time when document loaded.