# jQuery Keyboard shortcut plugin unbind does not work in my demo but does not show any errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to use this **jQuery Keyboard shortcuts plugin** https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys in my JavaScript app.

I am having an issue where the bind method which enables the event listener to start listening for my key presses works however the `unBind` method does not seem to be working.

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/80k2uf3w/13/

```
// Enable our keyboard shortcut for the "number 1 key"
function bindOneKey(){
    alert("keyboard Event listener is now listening for key number 1 to be pressed!");
    jQuery(document).bind('keydown', '1',function (evt){
        alert("keyboard key number 1 was pressed");
        return false;
    });
}

// Disable our keyboard shortcut for the "number 1 key"
function unBindOneKey(){
    jQuery(document).unbind('keydown', '1');
    alert("keyboard Event listener for key number 1 has been killed!");
}

// Demo buttons to enable/disable our Keyboard shortcut Event listeners
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bindOne').bind('click', bindOneKey);
    $('#unBindOne').bind('click', unBindOneKey);
}
```

HTML Buttons for Demo

```
<input type="button" id="bindOne" value="Bind 1 keyboard key" />
<input type="button" id="unBindOne" value="unBind 1 keyboard key" />
```

On that demo page after pressing the `bind 1` button, you can then press the number 1 key on your keyboard and get an alert from the callback function.

After that if you press the `unbind 1` button and then press the `1 key` again, it still works instead of un-binding it!

**Does anyone know what the problem could be?**

This is just the most basic demo to show the functionality and the problem.  My real app will basically enable the keyboard shortcuts when a Modal is opened and then disable/unbind them when the Modal is closed.  That is why i need to get this working.

My other option is to find a new Keyboard shortcut library, there are about 50 of them it seems but I liked this one because it seems to be pretty lightweight and also built by a very well know JavaScript developer.  So I am posting here to see if we can get this one working 100% first.

One thing to note is that on the GItHub page for the library it seems the test files are using a `jQuery v1.4.x` older version, perhaps that could be part of the issue but I am not sure as majority of the library works and also I get no console errors!

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question with someone else trying to do the same thing enable and disable the keyboard shortcuts as a Modal opens and closes using this library in this question [jQuery Hotkeys - unbinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901720/jquery-hotkeys-unbinding)

It seems there isn't any perfect solution so I will probably look at other libraries or maybe just manually code the key shortcuts I need with jQuery without a library.  It might give me more control.